# Parse.com Push Notification Service with cocos2d-javascript native project

Tags: android, parse-platform, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I am trying to add push notification from the parse.com service which has its android sdk and following settings to cocos2d-JS project

Add parse sdk to lib ( I added it to runtime-src/proj.android/lib) and added as build path

Call Parse.initialize from the onCreate method of your Application class to set your application id and client key:

```
public void onCreate() {
Parse.initialize(this, "app_key", "client_key");
}
```

For this , I created a package name of com.mycompany.myapp in runtime-src/proj.android/src/

Now android manifest where I have to following things

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.mycompany.myapp">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>
  <application android:name="MyApplication" android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="cocos2djs"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   <activity android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryFullscreenTakeoverActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode"
             android:hardwareAccelerated="false" >
        </activity>
   <!-- Flurry permissions and settings -->     
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

  <!-- parse.com Requires this  -->
  <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
    -->
    <category android:name="com.mycompany.myapp" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<!-- End of the receivers for Push Notifications -->
  </application>
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <!-- Required for Android Id -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <!-- Required for InApp  -->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

  <!-- Parse push notifications permisison -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <!-- end of permission for parse push notif -->

</manifest>
```

But still this app is not getting registered for notification , I am trying to use parse.com push service with cocos2d-JS native project anyone where am I going wrong?